# When does isomorphism of two categories of categories implies isomorphism of their elemental categories?

Tags: category-theory

I've been trying to understand an analogue of Russell's paradox for categories (Please refer to this link for more details and preliminaries about my question: [Russell Pardox for naive category theory](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/1999-May/003117.html))

I don't understand the first lemma, specifically how does the presence of M and N in $C_1$ results in any arbitrary category in $C_1$ being isomorphic to some category in $C_2$? I feel like something was skipped in the sketch which is needed to understand it. So, it will be great if someone could shine light on this missing thing.

---

> (*The relevant part of the text is also copied here.*)

Just for reference, let me give some more details of my Russell
paradox for naive category theory.

### Setting:

We are working in a naive category theory setting, i.e.,
category theory where the foundation (set-theoretic or otherwise) has
been left unspecified.

**Definition.** A *category of categories* is a category $\mathcal C$ such that
(i) each object of $\mathcal C$ is a category,
(ii) for any objects $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal C$, the
morphisms from $A$ to $B$ in $\mathcal C$ are exactly the functors from $A$ to $B$,
(iii) for any object $A$ of $\mathcal C$, the identity morphism $1_A$ at $A$ is the identity functor on $A$,
(iv) the composition law for morphisms of $\mathcal C$ is given by
composition of functors.

**Definition.**  A category $\mathcal C$ is *universal* if
(i) $\mathcal C$ is a category of categories,
(ii) every category is isomorphic to some category which
belongs to $\mathcal C$.

> **Theorem.** There is no universal category.

### Proof

In order to give the proof, we use the following definitions and
lemmas.

Let $M$ be the category with exactly two objects $A$ and $B$ and
exactly three morphisms $1_A$, $1_B$, and $f: A\to B$.

Let $N$ be the category with exactly three objects $A, B, C$ and exactly
six morphisms $1_A, 1_B, 1_C, f: A \to B, g: B \to C, h: A \to C$.

**Lemma.** Let $\mathcal C_1$ and $\mathcal C_2$ be two isomorphic categories such that
(i) $\mathcal C_1$ is a category of categories,
(ii) $\mathcal C_2$ is a category of categories,
(iii) $\mathcal C_1$ contans categories that are isomorphic to $M$ and $N$.
Then every category belonging to $\mathcal C_1$ is isomorphic to some category belonging to $\mathcal C_2$, and vice versa.

*Proof (sketch).*  If $C$ is any category belonging to $\mathcal C_1$, there is an
obvious one-to-one correspondence between morphisms of $C$ and functors
from $M$ into $C$, and compositions of such morphisms are picked out by
functors from $N$ into $C$.
Thus the isomorphism types of categories belonging to $\mathcal C_1$ are determined by the isomorphism type of $\mathcal C_1$ itself.
Furthermore, the same goes for $\mathcal C_2$, because $\mathcal C_2$ also contains categories
isomorphic to $M$ and $N$.
The lemma follows.

**Definition.**  A category $\mathcal C$ is *autistic* if
(i) $\mathcal C$ is a catogory of categories,
(ii) $\mathcal C$ is isomorphic to some category which is an object
of $\mathcal C$.
$\ $  A category $\mathcal C$ is *pseudoautistic* if it is isomorphic to some autistic category.

**Lemma.** Let $\mathcal C$ be a category of categories such that
(i) $\mathcal C$ is pseudoautistic,
(ii) $\mathcal C$ contains categories isomorphic to $M$ and $N$.
Then $\mathcal C$ is autistic.

*Proof.*  This follows immediately from the previous lemma.

---

To prove the theorem, let $\mathcal C$ be a universal category.
Let $\mathcal D$ be the full subcategory of $\mathcal C$ consisting of all categories belonging to $\mathcal C$
which are not pseudoautistic.
Then $\mathcal D$ is again a category of categories.
Also, since $M$ and $N$ are not pseudoautistic, $\mathcal D$ contains
categories isomorphic to $M$ and $N$.

Suppose first that $\mathcal D$ is autistic.
Then $\mathcal D$ is isomorphic to some category $E$ which belongs to $\mathcal D$.
Then $E$ is pseudoautistic. Hence, by definition of $\mathcal D$, $E$ does not belong to $\mathcal D$.
This is a contradiction.
We have shown that d is not autistic.
It follows by the previous lemma that $\mathcal D$ is not pseudoautistic.
Since $\mathcal C$ is universal, $\mathcal D$ is isomorphic to some category $E$ which belongs to $\mathcal C$.
Hence $E$ is not psuedoautistic.  Hence $E$ belongs to $\mathcal D$.
Thus $\mathcal D$ is autistic.  This is a contradiction.
The theorem is proved.

Answer (score 1):

We write $\mathcal C(A,B)$ for the homset of arrows $A\to B$ in some category $\mathcal C$.

Let $\varphi:\mathcal C_1\to\mathcal C_2$ a category isomorphism.
Besides that functors from the two specific categories, 'the arrow' $M$ and 'the composition' $N$, encode the category structure, the main (implicit) statement is that $\varphi(M)$ must be isomorphic to $M$ and $\varphi(N)$ to $N$.

For any objects $C,X\in Ob\,\mathcal C_1$ we have $\ \mathcal C_1(X,C)\cong\mathcal C_2(\varphi(X),\,\varphi(C))$. 
Moreover, if $C=X$, we get isomorphism of the endomorphism *monoids*.

Applying it to $X=C=M$ yields that $\varphi(M)$ has exactly 3 endofunctors,  corresponding to the 3 endofunctors $M\to M$ (which themselves correspond to arrows of $M$), with the same monoid structure. 
Note that a nontrivial category $C$ has at least one more endofunctors as objects because of the constant functors and the identity. 
This itself shows that $\varphi(M)$ can have at most $2$ objects, and investigating endofunctors of categories with $1$ or $2$ objects leads to the more specific description of $\varphi(M)$.

Once $\varphi(M)\cong M$ is shown, based on this, one can also prove $\varphi(N)\cong N$, and then the rest follows.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, and for not spoiling the fun by giving the whole proof. At the moment, I am looking at endofunctors on categories with 1 object.

Comment: I'm actually not sure that my proposed solution works, nevertheless it gives some taste of the problem. If also the one point trivial category $L$ was  involved besides $M$ and $N$, then we would certainly get $\varphi(L)\cong L$ and thus $\varphi(M)$ must have exactly 2 objects..

Comment: I've made some progress (Please do see my posted documentation of it), but I don't quite clearly see any way forward. So, I'm to going to work on something else for a while in the hope that things will sort out with time.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer?**
Thanks to @Berci for his wonderful cues that I was able to discover following elementary insights.

*Number of Objects and Constant Endofunctors*

Number of objects of any non-empty category can be established by way of number of constant endofunctors on it because there exists a 1-1 to correspondence b/w them.

However, how can one distinguish constant endofunctors if one has just one category and its endofunctors? 
It turns out that following holds in the universe of categories:
Let $C$ be any category. Then any functor $F:C\rightarrow D$ is a constant functor iff $\forall \alpha:C\rightarrow C$, $\ F\circ \alpha=F$.

*A special bit*

Consider the category $\varphi(M)$. It has exactly three endofunctors: one being identity and other two being constant at each of the two objects. It can be proven that if there exists no map b/w the two objects of $\varphi(M)$, then one is able to create another functor which switches the objects i.e. it takes the object to the other object and vice versa. This is a contradiction, therefore there must exist at least 1 map b/w the two objects.

At this point, I am stuck. Perhaps, I will come back to the question later. Or somebody else will point out what I have missed but was staring at my face.